# compare two lists in python and print the difference

Tags: python, list

I have two lists and I want to print the difference between them (if there is 1 difference, it should print "1". How can I fix that?

So what I have is:

```
a= ["1","2","3"]
b= ["1","4","5"]
```

The answer should be 2.

Comment: What do you want for a=["x","y"] and b=["y","x"]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what do you mean by difference. If they are equal in length and you want to find out the difference, do:

```
c = [i for i in a if i not in b]
print len(c)
```

Comment: I meant the difference like this: A= ["Hai", "Bye", "Python"] B= [ "Hai", "Different11", "different"] --> it should return "2" (because: the lists differs on 2 values)

Comment: Have you tried my code? Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes I tried, but it didn't work (the result was 0, but should be 1)

Comment: What example did you use?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. It works!

Answer (score 1):

Use `set`:

```
print len(set(L1) - set(L2))
```

Test:

```
>>> L1 = [1,2,5]
>>> L2 = [8,1]
>>> len(set(L1) - set(L2))
2
```

Comment: I meant the difference like this: A= ["Hai", "Bye", "Woly"]        B= [ "Hai", "Bye", "different"]  --> it should return "1"

Comment: use WoLy's solution, just print len(r). Or if you need symmetric difference you can use r = list(set(L1) ^ set(L2))

Comment: @Loesje Check my edit.It is faster.